# Error reporting in CLI PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, php.ini

I've setup `php5-cli` and everything's working great except I keep getting emails containing deprecated notices such as:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
```

Within the cron files that are running I also have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

If I understand correctly that should report all errors except for notices and deprecated messages.  I also have this specified within the php.ini for cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` is evaluated *before* your `error_reporting()` function is called.

Just correct the file (replace `#` by `;`) and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect with the `and`s.  Based on what you have written, it will report all as long as its NOT both E_NOTICE and E_DEPRECATED, whereas you probably meant either or.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ ( E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED));
```

The above says, report all errors except E_NOTICE or E_DEPRECATED.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still sending deprecated emails.  Should I make a similar adjustment within the php.ini ?

Comment: Based on the this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/540208), the error is being thrown BY the command line client--meaning its happening before your script is being run.  Theoretically, yes, adding this to the php.ini file would work--but make sure you add it to the right one; there is a hierarchy to how configs get read in.